# What is the limit of $\frac{\Omega(n!)}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime number, and $\Omega(n) =$ the total number of prime factors of $n$ counting multiplicities.  We know that $\Omega(n)$ is completely additive, so:

$$
\frac{\Omega(n!)}{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \Omega(i) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{\pi(n)}\sum_{j = 1}^{\log_{p_k}(n)}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p_k^j} \right\rfloor = \\ \ \\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{\pi(n)}\sum_{j = 1}^{\log_{p_k}(n)}\frac{n - (n \mod p_k^j)}{p_i^j}  = \\ \ \\
\sum_{k = 1}^{\pi(n)}\sum_{j = 1}^{\log_{p_k}(n)}\left(\frac{1}{p_k^j} -\frac{(n \mod p_k^j)}{p_k^jn} \right)
$$

I'm thinking since the (infinite) sum contains $\frac{1}{p_i}, i=1..\infty$.  It makes me think it probably diverges.  However, when computing it it seems to be approaching the line $y = 4$ as in $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Omega(n!)}{n} = 4$; either that or it's actually going up very slowly (logarithmically), which still means it diverges.  Just would have to plug in a googleplex to get it past $y = 4$.

Here is some code to experiment with:

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(n):
    S = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        S += primeomega(i)
    return S

k = 1
N = 6000000
X = []
Y = []
stride = 1

for n in range(1000000, N, stride):
    F = float(f(n) / n)
    
    print(n, F)
    X.append(n)
    Y.append(F)
    
    
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

So what does this relative growth of $\Omega(n!)$ look like?  Any way using analytic number theory to take its density limit?

Comment: Note: you can take the upper bound of each of the two sums in the double summations to be $\infty$.  It does not matter!  As the sum still evaluates to only finitely many nonzero terms.  And each time a term is nonzero we definitely want to count it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your limit is infinity.

Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. We have $\omega(n)\leq \Omega(n)$.

Since $\Omega$ is completely additive, $\Omega(n!)=\sum_{k\leq n}\Omega(k)$.

This gives $\Omega(n!)\geq \sum_{k\leq n} \omega(k)$.

A standard method switching order of summation applies,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k\leq n}\omega(k)&=\sum_{k\leq n}\sum_{p|k}1\\
&=\sum_{p\leq n}\sum_{k\leq n/p}1\\
&=\sum_{p\leq n}\left(\frac np + O(1)\right)\\
&=n\log\log n +O(n)+O(\pi(n))
\end{align}
$$
where $\log$ is the natural log and $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes up to $n$.

Then
$$
\frac{\Omega(n!)}n\geq \log\log n +O(1)+ O(\frac{\pi(n)}n).
$$
By $\pi(n)=O(n/\log n)$, we obtain
$$
\frac{\Omega(n!)}n\geq \log\log n + O(1)+ O(\frac1{\log n}).
$$
The right side diverges to infinity.

Comment: Side question: how does one go about finding a denominator for $\Omega(n!)/n$ other than $n$ so that the limit takes on a finite value?

Comment: Any power of $n$ with the exponent greater than $1$, will give $\Omega(n!)/n^a \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: What I mean is how do we find a formula $g(n) = n \cdot \text{(something)}$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Omega(n)}{g(n)} = C$ for $C \neq 0$ a constant real number.

Comment: We can prove a similar upper estimate with the main contribution $\log\log n$. Thus, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Omega(n!)/(n\log\log n)=1.$$

Comment: Thanks, I will ask further questions on MSE about that if I need help there 

Comment: How is that $n \log \log n$ expression generally proven?  Chebychev's functions?

Comment: Yes, related. It comes from $\sum_{p\leq n}1/p$.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is to give an asymptotic formula for $\Omega(n!)$:

\begin{aligned}
\Omega(n!)
&=\sum_{k\le n}\Omega(k)=\sum_{k\le n}\sum_{p^a\|k}a=\sum_{a\le\log_2n}a\sum_{p\le n}\sum_{\substack{k\le n\\p^a|k,p^{a+1}\nmid k}}1 \\
&=\sum_{a\le\log_2n}a\sum_{p\le n}\left(\left\lfloor n\over p^a\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor n\over p^{a+1}\right\rfloor\right)
=\sum_{a\le\log_2n}a\sum_{p\le n}\left({n\over p^a}-{n\over p^{a+1}}+O(1)\right) \\
&=n\sum_{p\le n}\sum_{a\le\log_2n}{(p-1)a\over p^{a+1}}+O(\log^2n) \\
&=n\left(\sum_{p\le n}\frac1p-\sum_{p\le n}{1\over p^2}+\sum_{p\le n}\sum_{1<a\le\log_2n}{(p-1)a\over p^{a+1}}\right)+O(\log^2n).
\end{aligned}

By Mertens' formula, there is

$$
\sum_{p\le n}\frac1p=\log\log n+B+O\left(1\over\log n\right),
$$

where the constant $B$ evaluates to

$$
B=\gamma+\sum_p\left\{\log\left(1-\frac1p\right)+\frac1p\right\}.
$$

Differentiating the formula for geometric series gives

$$
\sum_{1<a\le\log_2n}{(p-1)a\over p^{a+1}}={2p-1\over p^2(p-1)}+O\left(\frac1n\right),
$$

so combining everything gives

$$
\Omega(n!)=n(\log\log n+C)+O\left(n\over\log n\right),
$$

where

\begin{aligned}
C
&=B-\sum_p{1\over p^2}+\sum_p{2p-1\over p^2(p-1)} \\
&=B+\sum_p{1\over p(p-1)}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: This is really helpful.  Thanks!  